# Responsiveness issues with multiple charts using Chartjs, the class "chartjs-size-monitor" is only getting applied for only one chart

Tags: charts, resize, chart.js, dom-events

I am using ChartJs library to create the Line Chart. I have **two** Charts on the page. I need to resize the Charts on opening of Side Menu. I have used a container div to wrap the canvas element and that worked fine when I only had one chart on the page.

Now when I have two Chart on the page, on opening of Side Menu, only one Chart is getting resized. The observation that I had is that probably resize event is only getting applied to only of the Charts and that's why the div with the class "**chartjs-size-monitor**" is getting applied to the first Chart. Please note that this div is being created by the ChartJs internally.

below is the class "chartjs-size-monitor" which get's applied as an adjacent tag of canvas tag.

```
<div class="chartjs-size-monitor"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand"><div class="">
</div></div>
<div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink"><div class="">
</div></div></div>
```

As a result of this tag, the class "**chartjs-render-monitor**" is getting applied to the canvas tag thus making it responsive.

```
<canvas id="chart_name1" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: 
 block; height: 582px; width: 1165px;" width="1747" height="873"></canvas>
```

However the div element with class "**chartjs-size-monitor**" is not getting applied to the second Chart.

Kindly let me know what could be done as a workaround in case of having multiple ChartJs Charts on the same page.

FYI, I have already tried making changes to the option of Charts like making

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false
```